# Disable complete form while other form is shown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I'd like to disable my `mainForm` while the `optionsForm` is set to shown.

To do this, I was thinking of putting an invisible form ontop of the `mainForm` so interactions are not possible (but only through mouse clicks, keyboard strokes would still work).

How can this be done?

Comment: That is what ShowDialog is for, it will open your second form as a Modal Dialog.

Comment: Why not `this.Enabled = false` where you open `optionsForm`?

Comment: @MarkHall Thank you, I wasn't aware of the `ShowDialog()` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do one of 2 things, either:

1) Display the form as a dialog. This will prevent the first form from being selectable while Form2 is visible.

```
Form f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();
```

or 2) Disable all the controls on the first form if you want to display in a non-modal way (which it sounds like you don't want).

```
Form f2 = new Form2();
f2.Shown += ToggleControls;
f2.Closing += ToggleControls;
f2.Show();

public void ToggleControls(object o, sender e)
{
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = !c.Enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Devator: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept as the answer if you it resolved your problem.

Comment: had to wait a couple of minutes before I could. Done now though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could hide the mainform while the other one is open:

```
this.Visible = false;
optionsForm.ShowDialog();
this.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works best with good performance. Try this in your main form `Button-Click` event.

```
try 
{
    form2 f = new form2();
    Enabled = false;
    f.ShowDialog(this);
    Enabled = true;
    f.Dispose();
} 
catch (Exception exception) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
```